# Custom URL in c# MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add custom URL to my application. For example, I have a report section and I want all the Controller in that section to start with "Report". Currently, my URL look like :

```
localhost:12345/MyReport
```

but I want it to look like

```
localhost:12345/Report/MyReport
```

MyReport is the name of my controller.

I tried to change the following code in Global.asax

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", 
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

By

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", 
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Report",
                "Report/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "MyReport", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But I get a page not found error when I try to access `localhost:12345/Report/MyReport`... Any clue?

Comment: You may have to map it before that default one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As crazy as this is at first, order matters. Routing will find the first route that matches, and serves it. Try putting the the default one after your new custom one.

Because of that, you're going to the controller of `Report`, and attempting to find the action of `MyReport`. Which is indeed not found.

Comment: So rule of thumb, always have the most generic route **last**.

Comment: @Gudradain You're probably looking for something where the controller is optional? Use something like `Report/MyReport/{action}/{id}` as your URL, and then use the default controller `MyReport`?

Comment: @StevenV Maybe... But the thing is that Report/... is a section. There are many reports in it (MyReport1, MyReport2, MyReport3, etc...). I guess I can add them one by one